# R Plot multiple series with par(new=T) - axis labels are overlaying each other, making the plot unreadable

Tags: r, plot, par

I'm plotting multiple data series.

```
colos=c('red','green','purple','pink','brown')
par(new=F)
for (i in 1:5)
{
  plot(dat[[i+1]],col=colos[i],cex=marksize,xlab='Reading #',ylab = 'Current')
  par(new=T)
}
```

My plot looks like this:[image: R plot with bad axis labeling]

Is there a way I can overwrite the plot axis with each iteration, but not overwrite the plotted points?

Comment: why not use `lines` or `points`?

Comment: I had problems when I tried that method. Is points the correct way to approach this problem, instead of plot with par(new=T)?

Comment: That's how I'd do it.  Plot the first one with your `plot` call, then use `invisible(lapply(2:5, function(i) points(dat[[i]], col = colos[i])))` for the rest

Comment: Could you post example code? I'm having trouble following these instructions. Is function(x) analogous to dat[[i]] in my example?

Comment: `function(x)` is an anonymous function.  I posted an answer to show an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the `lines` or `points` function(s) instead. Here's an example of how I usually go about this problem.  This way you only overlay points on top of the existing plot, instead of plotting one plot on top of another.

Plot the first one with your original `plot` call, then use `lapply` to overlay the other columns' points on top of that.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(10)))
colos <- c('red','green','purple','pink','brown')
plot(dat[[1]], col = colos[1], xlab = 'Reading #',   
     ylab = 'Current', ylim = range(as.matrix(dat)))
invisible(lapply(2:ncol(dat), function(i) points(dat[[i]], col = colos[i])))
```

[image]

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I need to rescale my y axis after every new data set is added.

Comment: In the original `plot` call, try setting `ylim = range(as.matrix(dat))` and that should fix it.  Also, I'm not sure about transparent points yet.  I need to research that (can't remember).

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the axes using `xaxt` and `yaxt`

E.g.:

```
plot(1:10)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(1:10, rnorm(10), xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", type="l")
axis(side=4)
```

[image]