# Different numeric values shows up in wrong ratio in R Plot

Tags: r, analytics, finance

I am trying to plot two different values into the same plot, of a cumulative return on $1 invested in two different assets using this:

```
plot(USSMI$Dates, USSMI$Invest, type = 'l', xlab = "Dates", ylab = "ROI", col="Blue", main = "Return on $1 Invested in Market Index")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(USTB$Dates, USTB$Invest, type = 'l', xlab = "Dates", ylab = "ROI", main = "Return on $1 Invested", col="Red")
```

One value is close to 6000, and the other is close to 20, so why do they end up in the same place, and not in a correct ratio?

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOZyH.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Plot multiple series with par(new=T) - axis labels are overlaying each other, making the plot unreadable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567196/r-plot-multiple-series-with-parnew-t-axis-labels-are-overlaying-each-other)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567196/r-plot-multiple-series-with-parnew-t-axis-labels-are-overlaying-each-other